# First onchange checkbox execution doesn't run correctly function React Native Help pls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

In my first execute my function doens't work.
I need a checkbox that adds or subtracts numbers. but it doesn't work on the first run, only on the next ones. console.log () works, but it only adds or subtracts in the second run onwards.

````
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      valOp1: false,
      cotacao: 0.0,
      cont: 1,
    };
  }

  op1 = value => {{
    this.setState({ valOp1: !this.state.valOp1}); 
    if(this.state.valOp1 == true){
      console.log('selected');
      this.setState({ cotacao: this.state.cotacao + 10});
      console.log(this.state.cotacao);
    }
    else if(this.state.valOp1 == false){
      console.log('not selected');
      this.setState({ cotacao: this.state.cotacao - 10});
      console.log(this.state.cotacao);
    }  
  }
  this.funcop1();
}
  funcop1(){
       
  }

  render(){
    return(
    <View>
    <TextInput
    label="Valor Fipe"
    value={this.state.val}
    maxLength={11}
    keyboardType="numeric"
    onChangeText= {(val) => this.setState({val})}
    />
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.checkTitle}>Opcionais:</Text>
      <View style={styles.checkboxContainer}>
       <CheckBox
         value={!!this.state.valOp1}
         onValueChange={this.op1}
         style={styles.checkbox}
        />
        <Text style={styles.label}>Do you like React Native?</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
    </View>
    );
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call setState and expect the state to be changed immediately because setState is asynchronous. Just calculate the new state.valOp1 and use that value to calculate cotacao and then set state once.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      valOp1: false,
      cotacao: 0.0,
      cont: 1,
    };
  }

  op1 = () => {
    //calculate new value of valOp and cotacao first
    const valOp1 = !this.state.valOp1;
    const cotacao = valOp1
      ? this.state.cotacao + 10
      : this.state.cotacao - 10;
    //just set the state once
    this.setState({ valOp1, cotacao });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={this.state.valOp1}
          onChange={this.op1}
        />
        <pre>
          {JSON.stringify(this.state, undefined, 2)}
        </pre>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```